# Override only parts of a method

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I want to override the method `setText` in my `JDoubleField` that extends `JTextField` to filter the parameters to guarantee that the input is parse-able. The filter itself is a short piece of code, but I have no idea what the rest of the contents of the method are, so I wanted to have something like:

```
 @Override
    public void setText(String sText)
    {
        try{
            Double.parseDouble(sText);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            sText = "";
        }

      // The original method goes here.
    }
```

Any idea on how I could be able to do that?

Comment: `super.setText(sText);`?

Comment: After your custom code call `super.setText(sText)`

Comment: Thank you all for your help and quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you call `super` to execute the rest of logic.

```
super.setText(sText);
```

Comment: The first portion of your comment is actually incorrect because super() refers to the parent classes constructor with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I just type so quick

Answer (score 1):

If you call super.setText() after your custom code, it will run the original method that you overrided.

```
@Override
public void setText(String sText)
{
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(sText);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        sText = "";
    }

  // The original method goes here.
 super.setText(sText);

}
```